# Record can't be indexed when use generic

Tags: typescript

Consider following code.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitOverride=true&ts=5.2.0-dev.20230624#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAaShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwBooAVNTHAqAJQgGM4TcVbjyVAHxCoAXigBvAFBQoAawgh8ALijJZUAG4BDADYBXCGrrSAvtOkAzA9g7AycbFABGOkogYYseQvCQA5ACMAVAAPlABAEwBtJJQQWoBOrFQUUkuoWYiABS4EFYmANoBuoYQAQC6tIogxQG1+FUAlFKaAPTt9ODQAXRFAESNA5WhHDrY2HDArtAG+BC4UMBwUBT56Ms9kf0DZUYjAQB0OVEArADMAGzNmiQQwAYkzvlWRbWVANzmQA)

```js
type Foo<K extends string, T extends Record<K, string>> = {
  keys: K
  value: T
}

function bar<T extends Foo<'1' | '2', { 1: 'a', 2: 'b' }>>(def: T['value'], key: T['keys']) {
  // Type 'T["keys"]' cannot be used to index type 'T["value"]'.(2536)
  return def[key];
}
```

The `T['value']` do be index by `T['key']` but ts complain it's not allowed.

Why this strange behavior happens? Could you provide a correct snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your keys are strings `'1' | '2'` and `value` has number keys:`1: 'a'; 2: 'b'`.

You can fix the issue just by making both of them either strings or numbers:

```
function bar<T extends Foo<'1' | '2', { '1': 'a'; '2': 'b' }>>(
  def: T['value'],
  key: T['keys'],
) {
  return def[key]; // no error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep proper mapping with keys of your record type. This means you need to extend keys from the record and not use all amount of strings by `string` type. Here your code:

```
type Foo<K extends keyof T, T extends Record<K, string>> = {
  keys: K
  value: T
}

function bar<T extends Foo<1 | 2, { 1: 'a', 2: 'b' }>>(def: T['value'], key: T['keys']) {
  return def[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic argument you pass to `bar` is incorrect. In type `Foo` `T extends Record<K, string>` where `K extends string` but you defined keys of type `number`.

```
type Foo<K extends string, T extends Record<K, string>> = {
  keys: K
  value: T
}

function bar<T extends Foo<'1' | '2', { "1": 'a', "2": 'b' }>>(def: T['value'], key: T['keys']) {
  // Type 'T["keys"]' cannot be used to index type 'T["value"]'.(2536)
  return def[key];
}
```